# Change value based on column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a simple SQL query like this that I made with MS Access:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MID(table1.OZ, 1, 8) as OZ, table1.column1, table1.Description, table1.PSet
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table2.OZ = table1.OZ AND 
table1.column1= table2.column1
```

The table looks something  like this:

| OZ | column1 | Description | Pset |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.02.03 | some text | description | pset_LG |
| 01.02.03 | some text | description | pset_Text |
| 01.02.03 | some text | description | pset_ULG |

The OZ consists of numbers like this: `xx.xx.xx` and Pset always has three possible values: pset_LG, pset_Text and pset_ULG. Now to my question:

I want to change OZ based on Pset. If I have pset_LG, I'd like to cut off the last four numbers, so that OZ will show only `01`. And if I have pset_Text, I'd like to extract the third and fourth number (`02`) and for pset_ULG I'd want `03`, so the last two numbers. Is it possible to change my initial SQL query, so that the table gets adjusted? I tried making a new query in MS Access with `UPDATE [table]`, but I get an error saying that the operation must use an updateable query. I generally can't really seem to get my head around my problem so I'd really appreciate all kinds of help.

Comment: What does the query in your question have to do with your requirement? Do you want to update table1 or do you want a SELECT query?

Comment: Anything is fine as long as the OZ gets filtered based on Pset. The answer from Gordon Linoff works perfectly fine though! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional logic:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MID(table1.OZ, 1, 8) as OZ,
       table1.column1, table1.Description,
       table1.PSet,
       IIF(table1.PSet LIKE "*LG", MID(table1.OZ, 1, 2),
           IIF(table1.PSet LIKE "*Text", MID(table1.OZ, 4, 2),
               IIF(table1.PSet LIKE "*ULG", MID(table1.OZ, 7, 2), table1.OZ
                  )
              )
           ) as new_OZ
               
FROM table1 INNER JOIN
     table2
     ON table2.OZ = table1.OZ AND table1.column1 = table2.column1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT MID(table1.OZ, 1, 8) as OZ,
   table1.column1,
   table1.Description,
   table1.PSet,
   CASE
      WHEN PSet = 'pset_LG' THEN MID(OZ, 1, 2)
      WHEN PSet = 'pset_Text' THEN MID(OZ, 4, 2)
      ELSE MID(OZ, 7, 2)
   END as short_OZ

FROM table1, table2
WHERE table2.OZ = table1.OZ AND 
table1.column1= table2.column1
```